# Помогите, как взять след, элемент списка?

Tags: python

Имеются 10 гирь весом 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200. 1400, 1500, 2000 и 3000 г.
Сколькими способами гирями этого набора можно составить вес в v грамм. Набор гирь 1, то есть нельзя брать 2 раза по одной и той же гири.

```
weights=[100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1500, 2000, 3000]
v=int(input("Введите желыемый вес до 10900 гр: "))
s=0
for i in range(10):
    a=weights[i]
    for k in range(10):
        b=weights[k]
        for l in range(10):
            c=weights[l]
            for q in range(10):
                d=weights[q]
                for w in range(10):
                    n=weights[w]
                    for e in range(10):
                        f=weights[e]
                        for r in range(10):
                            g=weights[r]
                            for t in range(10):
                                h=weights[t]
                                for y in range(10):
                                    j=weights[y]
                                    for u in range(10):
                                        o=weights[u]
                                        if (a+b==v or a+b+c==v or a+b+c+d==v or a+b+c+d+n==v or a+b+c+d+n+f==v or a+b+c+d+n+f+g==v or a+b+c+d+n+f+g+h==v or a+b+c+d+n+f+g+h+j==v or a+b+c+d+n+f+g+h+j+0==v):
                                            s+=1
print(s)
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы он брал след. элемент? Потому что в данном виде он выдает ошибку, что такого индекса не существует. Также после его запуска он не выводит ответ.

Как найти количество комбинаций данного набора я понял и написал. Но как вот эту махину переделать во что-то читабельное? Все надо сделать с использованием циклов for.

Сама задача: Имеются 10 гирь весом 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200. 1400, 1500, 2000 и 3000 г.
Сколькими способами гирями этого набора можно составить вес в v грамм

```
weights=[100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1500, 2000, 3000]
v=int(input('Input weight:'))
s=0
if weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            if a+b==v:
                if a==b: continue
                s+=1
elif weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                if a+b+c==v:
                    if a==b==c or a==b or a==c: continue
                    s+=1
elif weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    if a+b+c+d==v:
                        if a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d or b==d: continue
                        s+=1
elif weights[5]+weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    for h in range(len(weights)):
                        e=weights[h]
                        if a+b+c+d+e==v:
                            if (a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d
                                or b==d or a==b==c==d==e or a==e or b==e or c==e or d==e): continue
                            s+=1
elif weights[4]+weights[5]+weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    for h in range(len(weights)):
                        e=weights[h]
                        for x in range(len(weights)):
                            f=weights[x]
                            if a+b+c+d+e+f==v:
                                if (a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d
                                    or b==d or a==b==c==d==e or a==e or b==e or c==e or d==e or a==b==c==d==e==f or a==f or b==f or c==f or d==f or e==f): continue
                                s+=1
elif weights[3]+weights[4]+weights[5]+weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    for h in range(len(weights)):
                        e=weights[h]
                        for x in range(len(weights)):
                            f=weights[x]
                            for z in range(len(weights)):
                                g=weights[z]
                                if a+b+c+d+e+f+g==v:
                                    if (a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d
                                        or b==d or a==b==c==d==e or a==e or b==e or c==e or d==e
                                        or a==b==c==d==e==f or a==f or b==f or c==f or d==f or e==f
                                        or a==b==c==d==e==f==g or a==g or b==g or c==g or d==g or e==g or d==g): continue
                                    s+=1
elif weights[2]+weights[3]+weights[4]+weights[5]+weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    for h in range(len(weights)):
                        e=weights[h]
                        for x in range(len(weights)):
                            f=weights[x]
                            for z in range(len(weights)):
                                g=weights[z]
                                for m in range(len(weights)):
                                    u=weights[m]
                                    if a+b+c+d+e+f+g+u==v:
                                        if (a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d
                                            or b==d or a==b==c==d==e or a==e or b==e or c==e or d==e
                                            or a==b==c==d==e==f or a==f or b==f or c==f or d==f or e==f
                                            or a==b==c==d==e==f==g or a==g or b==g or c==g or d==g or
                                            e==g or d==g or a==b==c==d==e==f==g==m or a==m or b==m or
                                            c==m or d==m or e==m or f==m or g==m): continue
                                        s+=1
elif weights[1]+weights[2]+weights[3]+weights[4]+weights[5]+weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    for h in range(len(weights)):
                        e=weights[h]
                        for x in range(len(weights)):
                            f=weights[x]
                            for z in range(len(weights)):
                                g=weights[z]
                                for m in range(len(weights)):
                                    u=weights[m]
                                    for r in range(len(weights)):
                                        p=weights[r]
                                        if a+b+c+d+e+f+g+u+p==v:
                                            if (a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d
                                                or b==d or a==b==c==d==e or a==e or b==e or c==e or d==e
                                                or a==b==c==d==e==f or a==f or b==f or c==f or d==f or e==f
                                                or a==b==c==d==e==f==g or a==g or b==g or c==g or d==g or
                                                e==g or d==g or a==b==c==d==e==f==g==m or a==m or b==m or
                                                c==m or d==m or e==m or f==m or g==m or a==b==c==d==e==f==g==m
                                                or a==r or b==r or c==r or d==r or e==r or f==r or g==r or m==r ): continue
                                            s+=1
elif weights[0]+weights[1]+weights[2]+weights[3]+weights[4]+weights[5]+weights[6]+weights[7]+weights[8]+weights[9]>=v:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        a=weights[i]
        for k in range(len(weights)):
            b=weights[k]
            for l in range(len(weights)):
                c=weights[l]
                for j in range(len(weights)):
                    d=weights[j]
                    for h in range(len(weights)):
                        e=weights[h]
                        for x in range(len(weights)):
                            f=weights[x]
                            for z in range(len(weights)):
                                g=weights[z]
                                for m in range(len(weights)):
                                    u=weights[m]
                                    for r in range(len(weights)):
                                        p=weights[r]
                                        for q in range(len(weights)):
                                            w=weights[q]
                                            if a+b+c+d+e+f+g+u+p==v:
                                                if (a==b==c or a==b or a==c or a==b==c==d or c==b or c==d or a==d
                                                    or b==d or a==b==c==d==e or a==e or b==e or c==e or d==e
                                                    or a==b==c==d==e==f or a==f or b==f or c==f or d==f or e==f
                                                    or a==b==c==d==e==f==g or a==g or b==g or c==g or d==g or
                                                    e==g or d==g or a==b==c==d==e==f==g==m or a==m or b==m or
                                                    c==m or d==m or e==m or f==m or g==m or a==b==c==d==e==f==g==m==r
                                                    or a==r or b==r or c==r or d==r or e==r or f==r or g==r or m==r
                                                    or a==b==c==d==e==f==g==m==r==w or a==w or b==w or c==w or d==w
                                                    or e==w or f==w or g==w or m==w or r==w ): continue
                                                s+=1
print(s//2)
```

Comment: `b=weights[k+1]` - здесь вы выходите за границы индекса

Comment: Так как вы делаете всё-равно не получится - вы только две гири берёте максимум, а для каких-то весов можно будет больше гирь. Надо по-другому как-то перебор делать.

Comment: Ваш алгоритм делает не то, что требуется в задаче, поэтому вам нужен другой алгоритм, а не "след, элемент списка".

Comment: weights=[100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1500, 2000, 3000]
v=int(input('Input weight:'))
s=0
for i in range(len(weights)):
 a=weights[i]
 for k in range(len(weights)):
  b=weights[k]
 
  if weights[k] == weights[i]:
   continue
  if v == a+b:
   print(str(a) + str(b))
Вот так?

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import combinations
weights=[100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1500, 2000, 3000]
v = 1900 # example v

ans = 0
for n_comb in range(1, len(weights) + 1):
    for comb in combinations(weights, r=n_comb):
        if sum(comb) == v:
            ans += 1
print(ans) # 5
```

Однострочная реализация:

```
from itertools import combinations
weights=[100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1500, 2000, 3000]
v = 1900 # example v

print(sum(1 for n_comb in range(1, len(weights) + 1) 
    for comb in combinations(weights, r=n_comb) if sum(comb) == v)) # 5
```

Comment: В решении предполагается, что каждая гиря используется не более 1 раза, иначе очевидно, что нет смысла в ограничении веса.

Answer (score 0):

задачу можно решить рекурсией

```
def rec_weight(x, y, k=0):
    if x > y:
        k += 1
        k, p = rec_weight(x - y, y, k)
    else:
        p = x
    return k, p


def rec_filling(s, yy, m=[]):
    if yy[0] <= s:
        for y in reversed(yy):
            if s >= yy[0] and s >= y:
                if y == s:
                    m.append(y)
                    break
                else:
                    m.append(y)
                    new_s = s - y
                    rec_filling(new_s, yy, m)
                    break
    return m


def near_weight(x, xx):
    max_part, rest_part = rec_weight(x, xx[-1])
    res_result = rec_filling(rest_part, xx, [])
    print([xx[-1] for a in range(max_part)] + res_result)


weights = [100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1500, 2000, 3000]
for v in [99, 999, 1900, 2600, 4500, 9999]:
    near_weight(v, weights)
# []
# [500, 300, 100]
# [1500, 300, 100]
# [2000, 500, 100]
# [3000, 1500]
# [3000, 3000, 3000, 500, 300, 100]
```

Comment: я наверное что-то не понимаю , но почему при 9900 вы 3 раза используете по 3к но не используете 9 раз по 1к и т.д.?

Comment: зачем брать 9 гирь если можно взять 3

Comment: ну там же вроде в условии не сказано что минимальное количество гирь. А спрашивается сколькими способами

Comment: тогда задача становиться проще